# Google API to check number of indexed pages?

Tags: api, search

Is there a Google API similar to Yahoo and Bing's API's to check for the number of indexed pages on a specified domain?

For example, for Yahoo if I type in the following URL:

http://search.yahooapis.com/SiteExplorerService/V1/pageData?appid=MTSlade&query=http://www.dave-sellers.co.uk&domain_only=1&results=1

Then it will return some XML detailing the number of pages indexed as 'totalResultsAvailable'

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about an API but you can view the pages Google has indexed by doing a search like so:

```
site:http://thesitesurl.com
```

[Here is an example](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com). You could apply some logic to the pagination and number of items per page etc (or simply use the "Results 1 - 100 of about 9,100,000"). You could even choose to display 100 items per page by using [this sort of syntax](http://www.google.com.au/search?num=100&hl=en&q=site:http://stackoverflow.com&start=0). I'm not sure if this would fit your exact requirements, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your response, unfortunately I need the results to be returned in XML as I am building a reporting tool that parses various bits of XML and spits out statistics.

Answer (score 2):

With the still operating - but deprecated - Google search api you can do this:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=www.bbc.co.uk
```

The result returned is of type "text/javascript" which you can parse as a JSON. The field you are after is `estimatedResultCount`. There doesn't seem to be an option to return the results as XML, but all you need to do is convert the JSON to XML. I don't know what language you're using, but there's bound to be utilities to do this.

If you do not want to use a deprecated API, then use the new Custom Search API - but you'll need to sign up for an API key:

http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html

and here's details on how to construct your query:

http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/using_rest.html

Comment: Google Search API is completely deprecated. It does not work any more. They are going to discontinue Google Site Search API as well. Only thing left is Custom Search Engine which doesn't allow you to search within Google, just your site.